# useSelector renders component but useState doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, redux

This component works fine when I use useSelector or useState. It doesn't render whole component when I've tried to change slider value

```
    const Volume = () => {
    const volume = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.metronome.volume);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const volumeHandle = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        dispatch(setVolume(+e.target.value));
    };

    return (
        <div className={`${classes.mixer} ${classes.appear}`}>
            <p className={classes.title}>Volume level</p>
            <p className={classes.percentage}>{volume}%</p>
            <input
                className={classes.slider}
                type="range"
                value={volume}
                min="0"
                max="100"
                onChange={volumeHandle}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Volume;
```

but similar component (Bpm) renders every time when I move slider, and because of this, even if I'll remove the animation of the appearance of the component, the slider won't work smoothly

```
const Bpm = () => {
    const count = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.metronome.value);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [tempo, setTempo] = useState("Allegro");

    const plusHandle = () => {
        if (count < 333) {
            dispatch(increment());
        }
    };

    const minusHandle = () => {
        if (count > 0) {
            dispatch(decrement());
        }
    };


    const sliderHandle = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        dispatch(setValue(+e.target.value));
    };
   return (
        <div className={classes.appear}>
            <div className={classes.tap_box}>
                <p className={classes.text}>Tap</p>
                <p className={classes.tap}>4/4</p>
            </div>

            <div className={classes.bpm}>
                <div className={classes.minus} onClick={minusHandle}>
                    <Minus />
                </div>
                <p className={classes.num}>{count}</p>
                <div className={classes.plus} onClick={plusHandle}>
                    <Plus />
                </div>
            </div>
            <p className={classes.tempo}>{tempo}</p>
            <div className={classes.slider_box}>
                <input
                    className={classes.slider}
                    type="range"
                    value={count}
                    min="0"
                    max="333"
                    onChange={sliderHandle}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Bpm;
```

I'm new to this so I'd like to hear your thoughts on why this happens and how to fix it)

Here is link to the site https://xkhours.netlify.app/playing

Comment: Please use react developer tools extension in chrome to profile your app and check what actually causes rerenders. For me it doesn't work because the above link isn't running development build of react app.

Comment: Both components are rerendered on every slider change. The first one is probably faster. You can use [redux-debounced](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-debounced) here.